# How to synchronize the publishers and subscribers in extended PUB-SUB pattern with Intermediary in ZeroMQ in c++?

Tags: c++, architecture, synchronization, zeromq, publish-subscribe

[Extended `PUB/SUB` topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEgpx.png)
[image]

I have multiple publishers and multiple subscribers in a use case with 1 intermediary.

In the ZeroMQ guide, I learnt about synchronizing 1 publisher and 1 subscriber, using additional **`REQ/REP`** sockets. I tried to write a synchronization code for my use case, but it is getting messy if I try to write code according to logic given for 1-1 `PUB/SUB`.

The publisher code when we have only 1 publisher is :

```
//Socket to receive sync request
zmq::socket_t syncservice (context, ZMQ_REP);
syncservice.bind("tcp://*:5562");

//  Get synchronization from subscribers
int subscribers = 0;
while (subscribers < SUBSCRIBERS_EXPECTED) {

    //  - wait for synchronization request
    s_recv (syncservice);

    //  - send synchronization reply
    s_send (syncservice, "");

    subscribers++;
}
```

The subscriber code when we have only 1 subscriber is:

```
zmq::socket_t syncclient (context, ZMQ_REQ);
syncclient.connect("tcp://localhost:5562");

//  - send a synchronization request
s_send (syncclient, "");

//  - wait for synchronization reply
s_recv (syncclient);
```

Now, when I have multiple subscribers, then does each subscriber need to send a request to every publisher?

The publishers in my use case come and go. Their number is not fixed.

So, a subscriber won't have any knowledge about how many nodes to connect to and which publishers are present or not.

Please suggest a logic to synchronize an extended **`PUB/SUB`** code

Answer (score 0):

### Given the **`XPUB/XSUB`** mediator node is present,

the actual **`PUB`**-node discovery may be completely effort-less for the **`XSUB`**-mediator-side ( actually principally avoided as such ).

Just use the **reversed** the `XSUB.bind()`-s / `PUB.connect()`-s and the problem ceased to exist at all.

Smart, isn't it?

<kbd>**`PUB`**</kbd>-nodes may come and go, yet the <kbd>**`XSUB`**</kbd>-side of the Policy-mediator node need not bother ( except for a few initial `.setsockopt( { LINGER, IMMEDIATE, CONFLATE, RCVHWM, MAXSIZE } )` performance tuning and robustness increasing settings ), enjoying the still valid and working composition of the actual Topic-filter(s) **`.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, ** )`** settings in-service and may centrally maintain such composition remaining principally agnostic about the state/dynamic of the semi-temporal group of the now / later `.connect()`-ed live / dysfunctional <kbd>**`PUB`**</kbd>-side Agent-nodes.

Even better, isn't it?

Comment: I am sorry but I am finding this explanation difficult to understand. Okay let me explain the situation more clearly.May be it will help us get to the solution .In my publisher code , before calling send method, I have used sleep(1) for synchronizing the PUBs with the SUBs . But according to the ZeroMQ guide this is an inelegant way to achieve synchronization. So I want to synchronize them without using sleep() method. Now the solution to this was the code  (taken from guide) that I mentioned in my question.

Comment: But this is for situation in which we have 1 publisher and 1 subscriber without any intermediary/proxy/forwarder. But my use case is with the intermediary and has multiple PUBs and SUBs .Now the problem is how to synchronize the multiple PUBs with SUBs. I hope I am more clear now.@user3666197

Comment: @JosephIreland ...Can you please explain the answer.

Comment: @Joseph Ireland ...Can you please explain the answer.