# In which header file is the method smessage() defined in ZeroMQ?

Tags: c++, zeromq, pipeline

Below is the code in ZeroMQ that uses `smessage` method. I searched for its definition in the `zhelpers.hpp` header file, but it is not present there.

```
#include "zhelpers.hpp"
#include <string>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //  Process tasks forever
    while (1) {

        zmq::message_t message;
        int workload;           //  Workload in msecs

        receiver.recv(&message);
        std::string smessage(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size());

        std::istringstream iss(smessage);
        iss >> workload;

        //  Do the work
        s_sleep(workload);

        //  Send results to sink
        message.rebuild();
        sender.send(message);

        //  Simple progress indicator for the viewer
        std::cout << "." << std::flush;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you google it? The first search result is https://github.com/booksbyus/zguide/blob/master/examples/C%2B%2B/zhelpers.hpp which is the source, and it also shows a question on the zeromq-dev mailing list from 2011 with an answer.

Comment: Since you tagged the question as C++, I would recommend to not use the C API but one of the C++ bindings. There are several listed on https://github.com/zeromq?page=1, all of them providing more idiomatic interfaces.

Comment: Yes I searched google and also looked into the same link that you have provided. But I didnt find any reference of smessage() in it. I will be thankful if you provide a link to the 2011 question that you are referring to?@Jens

Comment: I am using cppzmq binding for C++ already

Comment: @Sorry, I misread the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smessage` is not a method. It is a variable of type `std::string` which is being created by using overloaded constructor that takes pointer and size.

BTW, you can use [`zmq::message_t::str()`](https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/84ab7a0fc6f8d9a1bdbc3ce42d84027dca4286d7/zmq.hpp#L388) function directly to get an `std::string`.

For example:

```
zmq::message_t msg;
// read some data...
std::string smessage = msg.str();
```

Comment: Can you please provide a link to read about this string variable ,string class, and str() method@Azeem

Comment: @Ayush: It's already a link in my answer. Click on `zmq::message_t::str()` and you'll be at its definition under `zmq::message_t` class.

Comment: @Ayush If you need some introduction to C++, I would recommend to take a look at the C++ tour: https://isocpp.org/tour.

Comment: @Azeem Can you please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229121/how-to-synchronize-the-publishers-and-subscribers-in-extended-pub-sub-pattern-wi    .

Comment: @Jens Can you also help me develop a solution to this question. I have  tried to find its answer .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229121/how-to-synchronize-the-publishers-and-subscribers-in-extended-pub-sub-pattern-wi

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string smessage(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size());
```

is not a call to a function `smessage` but the definition of a `std::string` variable calling the constructor

```
basic_string( const CharT* s,
              size_type count, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```